# Finding the Variance

Tags: probability, variance

A vat contains millions of marbles. $20\%$ of them have the number “$6$” carved on them, and the rest have the number “$17$” carved on them.

A man possesses $3$ eggs. A marble is drawn from the vat, and then he is given that number of cartons of a dozen eggs each. Find the expected value, variance, standard deviation and moment generating function of $Y$, the number of eggs he will own. This is all the information that is given to me.

I calculated the variance to be $2787.84$ which seems a little high to me. Here is how I got my answer: $V(x)= [(12(6)+3)^2(.2) + (12(17)+3)^2(.8)] - 180.6^2= 2787.84$. Am I on the right track?

My post was removed previously.  Am I asking this in a better way?

Comment: you want to make your title more relevant to the question.

Comment: Thank you!  This is appreciated.

Comment: I have calculated the same [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=144*%28%286%5E2*0.2%2B17%5E2*0.8%29-%286*0.2%2B0.8*17%29%5E2%29). $\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$